# Nodemailer error on production

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

i have such config of nodemailer

```
    import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import {email, emailPassword, emailService, emailName} from '../../config.json';

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(`smtps://${emailName}%40${emailService}:${emailPassword}@smtp.${emailService}`);


export function sendFeedBack(req, res, next) {
  const reason = chooseReason(req.body.reason);
  const email = req.body.email || ' не указан';

  var mailOptions = {
    from      : `MyDoc-TV`,
    to        : `ros.padalko@gmail.com`,
    subject   : `MyDoc-TV : ${reason}`,
    text      : 'Причина : ' + reason + '\n' +
                'Имя : ' + req.body.name + '\n' +
                'Фамилия : '+ req.body.surname + '\n' +
                'Телефон : '+ req.body.phone + '\n' +
                'Имейл : '+ email + '\n' +
                'Сообщение : '+ req.body.message
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(error) {
    if(error){
      return res.end({error:'error in mail servise'})
    }
    console.log('send succes');
    return res.end();
  });
}
```

and everything is goo on localhost, but when i put it on production server it's broke my server. with the error

```
_http_outgoing.js:542
    throw new TypeError('First argument must be a string or Buffer');
    ^

TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.end (_http_outgoing.js:542:11)
    at server/controllers/feedBackController.js:25:18
    at Nodemailer.<anonymous>
```

error only on production , i go to settings of mail see i need to confirm the unknown request from my server which is in london,i conform it, but still have error,THanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your `transporter.sendMail` call is **failing** in production and the error you see is caused because you are calling `res.end` with an Object as first argument.

As per https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding_callback you should be calling `res.end` with a String or Buffer and specifying the encoding of what you are sending.

However, the reason for which your nodemailer is failing is not exactly clear. You should first fix your `res.end` call and pass also the stringified `error` argument of your callback so you can have a better idea about what's happening. That error argument should display the reason about why nodemailer cannot reach your SMTP server. Possibly there is an issue with the network or your production infrastructure.

Also, you can take a look at the nodemailer docs in order to configure it properly. A good idea could be being more explicit by passing an object to the `createTransport` function:

```
function getTransport(smtp) {
  return nodemailer.createTransport({
    host:      smtp.host,
    port:      smtp.port,
    secure:    smtp.secure,
    ignoreTLS: smtp.ignoreTLS,
    auth:      smtp.username ? coerceAuth() : void(0)
  });

  function coerceAuth() {
    return {
      user: smtp.username,
      pass: smtp.password
    };
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!